# Vue Dynamic Form Fields with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to create dynamic form fields with the help of v-for and vuex. I have a v-for within another v-for. The adding step works well, however, when I delete the first form field that's there by default after adding a second one this happens: https://youtu.be/a5b0KaITPTo

This is the code I'm using for this:

Vuex action (the payload is an object that contains the two indices from the v-for's I'm using):

```js
removeMaterialAction({ commit }, payload) {
      console.log(payload.materialIndex);
      commit("REMOVE_MATERIAL", payload);
    },
```

Vuex mutation:

```js
REMOVE_MATERIAL(state, payload) {     

state.workOrder.tasks[payload.taskIndex].materials.splice(
        payload.materialIndex,
        1
      );
      //Vue.delete(state.workOrder.tasks[taskIndex].materials, index);
    }
```

I have tried using splice, Vue.delete, filter, and shift and all lead to the same result. If anyone can help me I'll greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/array-index-as-v-for-key-results-in-problems-when-removing-items-from-the-list/4982/10

Basically, create a unique id instead of using the index from the v-for. You can add this function to your root's "methods" object and call it on :key= like `uuid(object)`:

```js
     uuid(e) {
        if (e.uid) return e.uid;

        const key = Math.random()
          .toString(16)
          .slice(2);

        this.$set(e, "uid", key);

        return e.uid;
      }
```